# The purpose of covering the grill during cold weather

Tags: coolant, winter, temperature

In some countries it is quite popular to cover up the front grill in winter (especially on diesel engined cars). As I understand the intention is to inhibit airflow to the radiator, but why would you do that if coolant flow to the radiator is allowed by the thermostat only when operating temperature is reached? As far as I can tell it all it could do is cause harm, such as overheating and lost intercooler effectiveness.

[image: What is this???]

I've actually seen special plastic or fabric covers sold for specific models, so it must have SOME kind of use:

[image: Do you really need this thing?]

So what's the catch, when do you need one if your cooling system is in order? I've heard of people saying that sometimes the interior heater is so effective that the engine is having trouble keeping the temperature up, but how would covering up the non-functioning radiator work? Is cold air hitting the outer shell enough?

Comment: I assume this is more common in areas with cold climates. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, during cold weather only.

Comment: From my limited experience with a VAZ-21011 (probably with a faulty thermostat) when the temperature outside was below -30, the coolant never ever got into the big circle. The cabin heater didn't heat anything but the lower part of the windshield. Installing the cover (just a piece of cardboard) did fix that problem.

Comment: It could also be to protect the radiator.  Very cold air flowing over the thin veins of a radiator could drop the temperature lower than the freezing point of 50/50 antifreeze.

Comment: @Quassnoi I understand the limited use in the case of a faulty thermostat, but buying a new thermostat is cheaper than buying one of these fancy covers.

Comment: @HandyHowie In the colder countries we use stronger than usual mixtures, suitable for -35°C or even lower. I've never heard of anyone having their radiator frozen, unless the person poured water in it in an emergency and forgot to replace it. Buying a cover is definitely more expensive than a common coolant mixture.

Comment: So car heats up and you can use it to warm inside the car. I was doing it with vw t5 and with my seat ibiza mk4 :D

Comment: Just put cardboard plus a grill guard on Saturn (gas) because in winter the engine doesn't stay at operating temp. I'm trying it. Thermostat good. Engine Coolant Sensor always runs coldish, but warm to op temp while idling. Had it on a computer thing that indicated that and another sensor was faulty. I'm no mechanic. Its a trial at this point.
David
Alberta

Answer (score 11):

I can see a few reasons to do this:

- The weather in some places will be so cold that even with the thermostat fully closed the cooling system isn't able to warm the engine up to operating temperatures. Inhibiting air flow through the radiator will reduce the amount of heat rejected to the surroundings, ***allowing the engine to get up to temperature***. The cold environment lends to a reduced risk of overheating.
- Preventing air flow through the radiator grill helps ***reduce drag coefficient*** on some vehicles, which helps improve fuel economy. BMW has introduced a dynamic kidney grill on their 2016 7-Series for this purpose (provided the necessary conditions are met - so the system is never active on a hot day with the engine under load).
- Because ***everyone else is doing it*** and it looks "cool". Though this reason is more psychological than technical :)

I'm not sure if there is anything diesel-specific going on here.

Comment: Can't say I'm convinced. Why would the engine care if the radiator is covered or not if no coolant is going through? Pretty sure cold wind blowing at the side of the engine outer layer is not going to change the inside coolant temperature much. And these are definitely not used for reducing the drag coefficient, it's used exclusively in winter and without other drag reducing mods. "Everyone is doing it" is definitely true, but there must be some basis. And it's much more often used on diesels, which emit less heat as far as I know.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing There will still be some minimal amount of coolant flowing through when the thermostat is fully-closed; you can't have a cooling system designed to have zero flow. Inhibiting air flow through the radiator will minimize heat dissipation in the radiator via convection.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I've been thinking about diesels. They are more sensitive to cold weather since they rely on the engines reaching a certain temperature for autoignition to occur (think glow plugs), At least petrol engines can ignite through spark.

Comment: Trolling some diesel forums seems to indicate that they are primarily for getting the engine up to proper temperature faster and having heat in the cabin faster.

Comment: @JPhi1618  yes, same results.  Root cause=impatience....in many cases.  I want to be warm!!!!!

Comment: @Zaid There will? How much are we talking about here? Most thermostats I've seen close pretty darn tight, I doubt there would be enough leakage to cool the vehicle at all. And yeah, they are sensitive, because of the nature of diesel fuel. That's why they have glowplugs. After they do their job the engine works, it's not going to stall because of low outside temperatures, why cover the grill?

Comment: @JPhi1618 That's what I thought and I fully understand the desire of quick heat, but how the hell would it work? Radiator coolant circle is cut off if the cooling system is in shape, wind blowing on the engine outer shell shouldn't noticeably impact the temperature. Should it?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing, Almost sounds like a new question...  I'm honestly not sure - I just searched for winter grill covers to see why people were buying them.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That was the purpose of this question, why people use these things if they seemingly do nothing? They must have a real purpose.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  The original question does specifically ask about coolant flow - sorry still waking up this morning.  Maybe edit the question and set that part of the question off to make it stand out?

Comment: Glow plugs on a diesel are for heating regular old ambient air up to autoignition temperature.  They aren't sufficient to warm the entire block up in cold weather.  And many diesel engines don't have glow plugs.

Comment: Some diesel engines, such as the Cummins 5.9L, use grid heaters in the intake manifold to help with cold weather starts.  They are essentially a wire mesh across the intake horn.  When you turn the key to the 'on' position in cold weather, a solenoid kicks on and runs around 200-300A of current through the grid heaters for anywhere from 10 seconds to a minute, depending on how cold it is.  Then a dash indicator tells you it's safe to start.  After starting, the grid heaters will run again.  This is *only* to get the intake air warm enough to allow ignition.

Comment: Air flowing through the grille openings doesn't just flow through the radiator.  It also flows through the engine bay.  For gasoline engines, this isn't enough to keep the engine from reaching operating temperature until you get down well below zero degrees fahrenheit.  But for diesel engines - particularly in a spacious engine bay with a generously sized grille opening - this can prevent the engine from reaching operating temp when the ambient temperature is only 10-15 degrees fahrenheit.

Comment: Running a diesel engine well below operating temperature is very, very hard on it.  The oil will be thicker than optimal, and components will not expand to proper tolerances, which means significantly increased engine wear.  Fuel economy suffers dramatically, because it isn't being burned completely.  This can also result in fuel washdown, where unburned fuel collects in the cylinders and washes down the cylinder walls, which carries away oil and results in damage to the cylinder walls.  In extreme cases, this can happen enough to dilute the engine oil and cause catastrophic engine wear.

Comment: Blocking the grille openings on a diesel not only shortens the warm-up period, but it also makes it easier to maintain operating temperature.  This improves fuel economy and decreases engine wear.

Comment: Today, I started my diesel truck with an ambient air temp of zero degrees fahrenheit.  It took several minutes of revving it up at 1500rpm (redline is 3200) to get it to finally smooth out and stop spewing white exhaust.  Right now, it's so cold that I can't get it to operating temp without putting a load on the engine, so I have to depart as soon as all cylinders are firing smoothly.  Today, driving without any grille cover, I drove for 15 minutes at 40-50mph before the temp needle reached 120 degrees fahrenheit.  It never reached operating temp (170) during my 20 minute commute.

Comment: Also, an engine thermostat does not prevent all coolant flow to the radiator when closed.  It only blocks off one side of the radiator - the one fed directly by the water pump - to prevent the water pump from forcing coolant directly through the radiator.  The other end of the radiator is still open to the coolant system even when the thermostat is closed, and can serve as a pathway for heat to escape from the engine.  When ambient temps are extremely cold, this passive mixing of super-chilled radiator coolant with warm engine coolant can be enough to keep an engine from warming up.

Answer (score 8):

This is old, but some of these comments annoy me.  I live in Fairbanks AK and drive a 90's diesel Chevy. It takes a 15 minute idle period (in addition to at least an hour with the block heater plugged in) and 3-5 miles of highway driving for the coolant temp to get over 120 degrees when it's 10 degrees or colder. When the temp is below -20f or so, the coolant will never reach the proper operating temp, even pulling steep hills at 70mph. My rad cover lets my temps be in acceptable operating range in less time, which reduces idling and engine wear. Enough cooling takes place to prevent overheating, though I will take it off if I need to tow when it's that cold. It's also not true that closed thermostats prevent all water movement, they are not water tight.

Comment: On my 90s Dodge with the Cummins 5.9L, I can't even idle it up to operating temp.  Cummins explicitly states that, in cold weather, you should not idle it for more than 10 minutes (that's even after it's up to operating temp) because fuel washdown will starve the cylinders of oil and dilute the oil in the pan - at idle in sufficiently cold temps, the cylinders don't stay hot enough to burn all the fuel, and it collects in the cylinders.  I have to run it at 1500rpm or higher to get it to move the needle, and if its cold enough (under 15 degrees F), it never warms up like this.

Answer (score 6):

An anectodal answer to this...

Back in the '70s I owned a [Moskvich 412](http://www.oldrussiancars.com/moskvich-412/), a Russian car built to survive in Siberia.  This had a brass venetian blind arrangement in front of the radiator that could be opened and closed from a lever beside the steering wheel.

The handbook stated that this blind should be closed when starting the vehicle at temperatures below -10ºC and should be opened when the temperature gauge reached normal.  It also said that in temperatures below -40ºC it should never be opened.  The reasoning given was that the blind reduced airflow throughout the engine compartment, not just through the radiator itself.  This gave the engine a chance to reach an efficient temperature.  But of course the blind could be opened if the engine started to overheat.

So, yes, there is a point to blanking the radiator and it doesn't cause damage if you keep an eye on the temperature gauge.

The car had a petrol engine, not diesel.  There is nothing particular about blanking the radiator of a diesel.  As the weather never gets that cold in Southern England I never closed the blind in anger.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple answer here. Autos and trucks were designed with an expectation of outside temperatures of aprx 65 degrees up to 110 degrees aprx. the entire engine system is designed to run fairly well under these temps. However as anybody in these cold areas knows It may be cold, but wind chill makes it worse! When you drive your adding windchill to your radiator! By blocking the majority of the grill opening you in effect make the space smaller as well as blocking the wind so heat can assist in controlling radiator freeze from excessive cold at the cores. Hope this helped. Additional information on Thermostat function. This device sets in the engines upper block inside a pocket of coolant. Only when the coolant reaches a temperature the device is set for will the device open and allow coolant flow but only till the coolant flow temp has dropped under the set range and again it closes. The thermostat is meant to slow or fully stop the flow till the radiator up front is able to cool the coolant to the point it will dissipate heat again from the block. The block water temp is far hotter than is the radiator thermostat temp. If allowed to simply flow the block would heat the water to boiling point without the thermostat holding back and allowing the air passing around the core to cool the coolant suffsiantly.

Comment: I don't believe you read the entire question. Why does "windchill" to the radiator matter if the thermostat handles engine temperature anyways?